# Memory Management in Objective-C, property return an objc-c object with a +1 retain count, UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I ran the analyzer and I'm not sure how a couple of memory management things work.  I have a property (it does not have custom setters or getters):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Then I try to use it later:

```
if ([[MyClass sharedDelegate].myArray containsObject:"test"])
```

It says "property returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count"

Where `sharedDelegate` is defined as:

```
+(MyApp*)sharedDelegate
{
    return (MyApp*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

I don't understand this since I don't see where the retain is?  I thought that using the property in this way is using the getter method which just returns the value of `myArray`.  So where is the memory leak?

It then points to

```
UIGraphicsBeginImagecontextWithOptions(container.bounds.size, YES, 1.0);
```

> Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

I also do not understand this, or how this relates to the first memory leak.  They seem unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the getter for myArray? @synthesize, or custom?

I think the error could also be in sharedDelegate. Don't retain when returning a singleton.

The second one seems unrelated. Maybe you didn't call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`. If you call it in some other function, that might be ok. The compiler is expecting the normal pattern of calling those two functions in the same function, but it is not required.

Comment: I added the sharedDelegate method to help narrow down the problem since I still don't see the error.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have marked the property to return a retained reference.

Comment: retain means retain on set, not retain on get.